# Java GUI JMenuBar

Tags: java, user-interface, jmenubar

Ok I have a GUI with and `JMenuBar` and when I load it sometimes it won't show, but if I minimize it and click back on it, the `JMenuBar` Shows.  Where is my problem? and how can I fix it?  oh and if I re size it to, the `JMenuBar` appears.

Here is my code

```
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JMenu;
 import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
 import javax.swing.JMenuItem;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame =  new JFrame("TwitchBot");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    KeyGetter.LoadKeys();
    try {
        Config.loadConfig();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();


    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    mb.add(file);
    JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
    mb.add(edit);
    JMenuItem options = new JMenuItem("Options");
    options.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Config.openConfig(frame);
        }
    });
    frame.setJMenuBar(mb);
    edit.add(options);
  }
}
```

Comment: you should `pack()` and show the `JFrame` after you add all the elements to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure you're creating/modifying your UI only from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details
- Call `pack` and `setVisible` only after you have established the base UI.

Comment: Thanks mad, you fix it!

Comment: I have another question... should i post here or make new thread?

Answer (score 0):

NEVER USE pack() ..it has conner cases.. some times it fails. From experimentation I have learnt to  always call repaint() right before calling setVisible(true) this never fails. Call repaint() right before you call setVisible(true).--THIS NEVER FAILS.

```
  repaint();
  setVisible(true);  // assured NEVER FAILS.
```